# How to get output parameter from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure that inserts data into multiple tables; I want the `suburbID` to be an output parameter, but when I insert a `suburbName` that already exists, the stored procedure does not run properly. What's wrong with it? Maybe I missed something?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertAddress]    
    @SuburbName NVARCHAR(50),
    @PostalCode NVARCHAR(50),
    @CityName NVARCHAR (50),
    @ProvinceName NVARCHAR (50),
    @SuburbID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProvinceID INT
    DECLARE @CityID INT

    SELECT @ProvinceID = ProvinceID 
    FROM tblProvince 
    WHERE ProvinceName = @ProvinceName

    SELECT @CityID = CityID 
    FROM tblCity 
    WHERE CityName = @CityName

    SELECT @SuburbID = SuburbID 
    FROM tblSuburb 
    WHERE SuburbName = @SuburbName

    IF (@ProvinceID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblProvince VALUES (@ProvinceName)
        SELECT @ProvinceID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    IF (@CityID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblCity VALUES (@CityName, @ProvinceID)
        SELECT @CityID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    IF (@SuburbID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblSuburb 
        VALUES (@SuburbName, @PostalCode, @CityID)        

        SET @SuburbID = @@IDENTITY
        RETURN
    END
END
```

This is how I call the procedure

```
public int InsertAddress(Address a, ref string suburbID)
{
        using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            dbComm = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertAddress", dbConn);
            dbComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuburbName", a.Suburb);
            dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalCode", a.PostalCode);
            dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityName", a.City);
            dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProvinceName", a.Province);
            dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuburbID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                dbConn.Open();
            }

            int x = dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            suburbID = dbComm.Parameters["@SuburbID"].Value.ToString();

            return x;
        }
}
```

Comment: *"when i insert a suburbName that already exists the stored procedure does not run properly"* what does "not run properly" not mean? Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-an-output-parameter)?

Comment: Are you able to show us CREATE TABLE statements for tblProvince, tblCity and tblSuburb? Also can you show us how you are calling the stored procedure and how you are getting the value of the output parameter.

Comment: @Larnu Im running this stored procedure through my asp.net c# system, when i insert a suburb with a name that matches an existing record the page just reloads and it doesnt return the output parameter

Comment: Have you run the stored proc directly in a client tool (such as SSMS or Azure Data Studio) to unit test just that piece and confirm whether the proc alone works as expected. That will help you work out whether it's an ASP issue or a database issue

Comment: Also, don't use `@@IDENTITY`, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!